# Do I have to create a new master zone for every site in webmin?

Tags: dns, webmin

I'm new to webmin and would like to use it for three sites.

Do I have to create a new master zone for each of my sites?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are those sites on different domains? E.g. example1.com, example2.com Or are they on the same domain, but different subdomains? site1.example.com, site2.example.com

Comment: yes, Actually I have site1.co, site2.com, site3.org for example

Answer (score 1):

It depends if you're using webmin to manage your own DNS or whether your using another company's DNS. This article explains it well (even though it's about a specific hosting company): http://rimuhosting.com/support/bindviawebmin.jsp

Comment: I have BIND DNS server, does that mean I can manage my own DNS?

Comment: Yes, but to do so you'd have to register a domain as a nameserver, i.e. buy a domain and register the ip that it serves names  for.